# Переустановка виндовс удаляет все вирусы?

Tags: windows, ос

При переустановке Windows удаляются ли все вирусы, которые можно подхватить, лазая в интернете и скачивая что-то?

И есть ли разница при переустановке винды между форматированием разделов и их удалением? Может ли остаться что-то, если раздел удалить, а не отформатировать?

Comment: Вирусы, которые заразили bios, - не удалит. Вирусы на каких-нибудь флешках, очевидно, тоже не удалит

Comment: @andreymal да и на соседних жестких дисках (или ssd) тоже всё останется (флешки за соседние диски не считаем).

Comment: А как удалить вирус если заражён биос? Только антивирусником, никак нельзя ничего скинуть (извините  если вопрос глупый)

Comment: Вытащить/выпаять чип биоса из материнки и на программаторе перепрошить оригинальной прошивкой. Но скорее всего с биосом всё должно быть в порядке — я давно не слышал о каких-либо эпидемиях заражений биосов

Answer (score 2):

Переустановка Windows удаляет вирусы, которые содержались в файлах Windows. Т.е. если заражена система и вы её переустановите, то файлы системы после этого будут без вирусов, но из каких-либо заражённых файлов, флешек и т.д. это вредоносный код не удалит.

Answer (score -4):

Переустановка виндос подразумевает собой полную очистку данных ПК. Естественно вирусы являющиеся файлами так же будут удалены. Не зависимо от того удалите вы или форматируете вирусов точно не будет.

Comment: Нет, не подразумевает.

Comment: Почему не подразумевает? Если форматирование всех разделов, то что-то разве может уцелеть? Я просто скачал одну программу крякнутую, она точно была зараженной, после ее ненадобностьи переставил ось, но теперь задумался, мог ли троян остаться

Comment: @Глеб потому что по умолчанию никто не заставляет форматировать разделы, тем более все. Можно даже системный раздел не форматировать — установщик новой винды просто перенесёт старую винду в папку `Windows.old` (и как следствие старые вирусы могут остаться внутри неё, если их специально не удалять)

Comment: Наверное парень имел в виду перестановку как у меня, с полным форматированием. А ещё вопрос, удаление разделов и форматирование - это же одно и тоже? На программном уровне. Ну есть же разница между разными уровнями форматирования. Может и тут есть какая разница в удалении файлов.

Comment: @Глеб удаление разделов и форматирование - это не одно и то же. Вы можете отформатировать раздел, не удаляя его. И вы можете удалить раздел и создать новый без форматирования. Форматирование - это разметка раздела под файловую систему. Разница в уровнях удаления: 1) файл не удаляется, просто не используется; 2) файл удаляется без затирания данных (тогда можно восстановить); 3) файл удаляется с затиркой данных нулями (в теории можно восстановить при помощи спецоборудования); 4) файл удаляется с затиркой данных псевдослучайными байтами (тогда с концами - восстановить нельзя).